# How do I pick only the files that are images?

Tags: android, image, file, random, while-loop

Im trying to pick only the files that are images And I succeed,
but now the app takes long to load..

Here's a part of my code:

**onCreate:**

```
filename(testimg);
            while (type != "jpeg" && type != "GIF" && type != "PNG"
                    && type != "BMP" && type != "WebP") {
                filename(testimg);
            }
```

**filename(function):**

```
public void filename(File filename) {
    abcd = filename.toString();
    File[] listFiles = filename.listFiles();
    Random r = new Random();
    File randomPicture = listFiles[r.nextInt(listFiles.length)];
    Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(randomPicture);

    convertedPath = randomPicture.getAbsolutePath();

    if (convertedPath.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
        String ext = convertedPath
                .substring(convertedPath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(mime
                .getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext));
        System.out.println(type);
    } else {
        type = null;
    }
    image.setImageURI(pictureUri);
}
```

***So im asking if there is more effective way?***

Answer (score 2):

```
 File[] listFiles = filename.listFiles( new FileFilter(){
@Override
public boolean accept(File file){
return file.isFile() && (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getName().endsWith(".png")); //add more extensions if needed

}
});
```

Comment: Best solution, this is how I would do it. But don't use contains here, use endsWith!

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to pick only the files that are images

Why not just use `OR`? I think this is better :

```
 while (type.equals("jpeg") || //more types) {
                filename(testimg);
            }
```

Because if any one of those `OR` is `TRUE`, then its an image file.